# Copy a Google Document INCLUDING the embedded script using Drive SDK

Tags: google-apps-script, copy, google-drive-api

I have a `Google Document` with an embedded `Google Apps script` that shows a sidebar to help create templates.

Next I `copy` this Google Document to the Google Drive of the end user using the `Google Drive SDK`.

I can see the copy of the Google document in the end user's Google drive but **the embedded script is not present for the copied Google Document**.

Question: Is it possible to copy the document over **with** embedded Google Apps script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did another test and the embedded script is copied ... a glitch ?!

Happy anyway.